# nHibernate join and take one record

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I'm doing the below join, there are many bookingActions records, but I want there to only be one BookingAction record per booking record. I want the BookingAction record that has the highest primary key value.

How would I do this?

```
var bookingLocationsQuery = (
        from
            booking in session.Query<Booking>()
        join
            bookingActions in session.Query<BookingAction>() on booking.Id equals bookingActions.bookingId

        where
            (booking.bookingAdminID == userId)
        select new { booking, bookingActions }
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions.  First, you should be leveraging NHibernate's `many-to-one` to do the join for you instead of doing it manually.  It looks like you currently have something like this...

```
public class BookingAction
{
    // ... other properties ...
    public virtual int bookingId { get; set; }
}
```

```
<class name="BookingAction">
    <!-- ... other properties ... -->
    <property name="bookingId" />
</class>
```

Don't do that.  Instead, you should have:

```
public class BookingAction
{
    // ... other properties ...
    public virtual Booking Booking { get; set; }
}
```

```
<class name="BookingAction">
    <!-- ... other properties ... -->
    <many-to-one name="Booking" column="bookingId" />
</class>
```

Similar advice for `Booking.bookingAdminID`.  It should be a `many-to-one` to `User`, not just a simple property.

Second, after you make those changes, you should be able to accomplish your goal with a query like this:

```
var subquery = session.Query<BookingAction>()
    .Where(a => a.Booking.Admin.Id == userId)
    .GroupBy(a => a.Booking.Id)
    .Select(g => g.Max(a => a.Id));

var bookingActions = session.Query<BookingAction>()
    .Fetch(a => a.Booking)
    .Where(a => subquery.Contains(a.Id));
```

Sorry about switching it to the chained extension method syntax - that's easier for me to work with.  It's exactly equivalent to the `from ... select` syntax in execution.

Comment: +1, nice answer, with essential point about the mapping. BTW I am using both properties (the `int` as readonly), but for relations, the many-to-one does the JOIN trick

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Max()` method, for sample:

```
var bookingLocation = session.Query<Booking>()
                      .Where(booking => booking.bookingAdminID == userId)
                      .Max(x => booking.bookingAdminID);
```

Comment: Essentially the same as `var bookingLocation = userId;`.  Also, inside `.Where(...)` should be a lambda expression.